# Setting cut off time per request at tomcat / jersey resource level

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS with apache tomcat 7 container. I am writing a server , where all the requests have to honour the  cutoff time (say 500 ms), beyond which I should terminate the request.It would be better If I can send some default httpresponse on timeout.

How do I do this in jersey? Can I have jersey resource filter throw some exception on cut-off time , which I can catch in ApplicationExceptionMapper and send a default response?  Probably starting the timer in a filter and let the timer on timeout of say 500 ms throw some exception.

Or do I have to set timeout in server.xml by setting connectionTimeout parameter to 500 ms.

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="500" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```